# When checking one check box the other check box must disappear

Tags: javascript, html

I have put together this section of code which does what it's supposed to do. The only problem is when I deselect the first checkbox the shopping cart box remains. I want the top box to be the master, so if that's not selected the program will display nothing. Here's what I have so far:

```js
function shoppingcartFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function shoppingcart1Function() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("shopping_cart");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text1");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="shoppingcartFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart:
<input type="checkbox" id="shopping_cart" onclick="shoppingcart1Function()">    <br /><br /></p>

<p id="text1" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="shopping_car" pattern="[A-Za-z]{ ,30}" maxlength="30" title="Max 30 characters" name="shopping_car" size="30" required>*
  <br /><br /></p>
```

Comment: Why do you not use native `radio` styled as checkbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can effectively simulate what you want in your `shoppingcartFunction()` by unchecking `#shopping_cart` and calling `shoppingcart1Function()` directly.

```js
function shoppingcartFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    
    document.getElementById("shopping_cart").checked= false;
    shoppingcart1Function();
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function shoppingcart1Function() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("shopping_cart");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text1");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
 Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="shoppingcartFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart:
<input type="checkbox" id="shopping_cart" onclick="shoppingcart1Function()">    <br /><br /></p>

<p id="text1" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="shopping_car" pattern="[A-Za-z]{ ,30}" maxlength="30" title="Max 30 characters" name="shopping_car" size="30" required>*
    <br /><br /></p>
```

Comment: @user5743264 if that helped, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the use of `radioButtons`, you can try this function:

[JQUERY FRAMEWORK REQUIRED!!]

```
// helper function to check the checkboxes
$(document).on("change", ".checkClass", function(event){

if($(this).attr( "checked") != "checked")
    //do something when box is unchecked
else
    //or when it becomes checked

});
```

You can react for box checks in this function, here you can add or remove the other one if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** If you want hierarchical structure - make the html appropriate. Put the second checkbox and the rest in the "master" element.
**Second:** don't use `p` where `div` belongs to.

```js
function shoppingcartFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function shoppingcart1Function() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("shopping_cart");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text1");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="shoppingcartFunction()">

<div id="text" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="shopping_cart" onclick="shoppingcart1Function()">

  <div id="text1" style="display:none"><label for="sender_name">Shopping Cart</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="shopping_car" pattern="[A-Za-z]{ ,30}" maxlength="30" title="Max 30 characters" name="shopping_car" size="30" required>*</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you, you want to hide all what is inside the p with id="text1".
So just get it with var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
and set its display to "none" if the first checkbox is not checked, otherwise do nothing.

```
function shoppingcartFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  alert("The first");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
    text1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

But you will have a problem: if the user checks the first checkbox, and than the second (with id="shopping_cart"), all what inside the p with id="text2" will be displayed.
If now the user unchecks the first checkbox, the second one and all what is inside the p with id="text1" will be hide. If again the user checks the first checkbox, the second one will be diplayed and it is checked but the p with id="text1" will not be shown.

To solve this second problem:

```
function shoppingcartFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");

  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("shopping_cart");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text1.style.display = "block";
    }        

  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
    text1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```